# I am trying to filter my list in an alphabetic order when I click a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title is showing, I'm trying to filter my list in an alphabetic order when I click on one of the characters (A, B, C, D ...) but I cannot get it to work.

This is my javascript code:

```
function makemyAlphabetplz(charA, charZ) {
    var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    return a;
}

var array = makemyAlphabetplz('a', 'z');

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  $('#alphabet').append('<li class="character">' + array[i] + '</li>');
};

var triggers = $('.character');
var filters = $('.title');

filters.each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('letter-' + $(this).text().substr(0,1));
});

triggers.click(function() {
    var takeLetter = $(this).text();
    filters.parent().hide();

    var matches = filters.filter('.letter-' + takeLetter);
    matches.parent().fadeIn(222);

    if (matches.length == 0) {
        alert('There is no result for ' + takeLetter);
    };
});
```

and this is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id="alphabet">
  </ul>

  <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Apple </h4>
  </div>
  [...]
</div>
```

I also made an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yupyxk0b/). I appreciate all help and explanation.

Comment: The question which you accepted doesn't solve both problems, while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404731/5583289) one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have a leading space for all of your items. That's why the `.substr(0, 1)` does not return the leading character but a space.

If you trim the item and convert it to lower case then it should work fine.

```
filters.each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('letter-' + $(this).text().trim().substr(0,1).toLowerCase());
});
```

```js
function makemyAlphabetplz(charA, charZ) {
    var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    return a;
}

var array = makemyAlphabetplz('a', 'z');

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  $('#alphabet').append('<li class="character">' + array[i] + '</li>');
};

var triggers = $('.character');
var filters = $('.title');

filters.each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('letter-' + $(this).text().trim().substr(0,1).toLowerCase());
});

triggers.click(function() {
    var takeLetter = $(this).text();
    filters.parent().hide();

    var matches = filters.filter('.letter-' + takeLetter);
    matches.parent().fadeIn(222);

    if (matches.length == 0) {
        alert('There is no result for ' + takeLetter);
    };
});
```

```css
ul#alphabet {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  list-style: none;
}
li.character {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #9b59b6;
}
.filter-me {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2ecc71;
  padding: 15px;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="alphabet">
  </ul>
  
  <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Apple </h4>
  </div>
   <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Broccoli </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Melon </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Rhubarb </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-me">
    <h4 class="title"> Strawberry </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try it.

**1. get text in all small letters and edit specifies where to start in the string**

original:

```
$(this).addClass('letter-' + $(this).text().substr(0,1));
```

edit:

```
$(this).addClass('letter-' + $(this).text().substr(1,1).toLowerCase());
```

**2. get text in all small letters**

original:

```
var takeLetter = $(this).text();
```

edit:

```
var takeLetter = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues:

1. The words `Apple`, `Broccoli`, etc. were surrounded by spaces. The `substr(0,1)` needed to be changed to `substr(1,1)` for this reason.
2. `takeLetter` is a lowercase letter, while the class names include uppercase letters. Just add `.toUpperCase()` to the end of this line: `var takeLetter = $(this).text();` would change to `var takeLetter = $(this).text().toUpperCase();`.

For a working version, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iONinja/yupyxk0b/1/).